# how to implement server side render in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, laravel, redux, server-side-rendering

I am working on react project which has laravel as backend, which is taking big hit on SEO results. so i reserched about it and i came to know about SSR. 
Topic seems very interesting but no one online has answer about many people have asked this question in comments but no ones question has been answered

i have used this package spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering but i m facing the issue after following the tutorial one guy posted online stepupcoding which is the only laravel react SSR tutorial available,I did the same thing but it didnt work it is giving error:

```
The command "node C:\wamp64\www\newGitRepo\storage\framework/ssr\f8ef279e430bf74f0394a21851fce988.js" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: C:\wamp64\www\newGitRepo\public

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
C:\wamp64\www\newGitRepo\storage\framework\ssr\f8ef279e430bf74f0394a21851fce988.js:189
/******/ \tvar jsonpArray = window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || [];
         \t                 ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/arrayWithoutHoles.js.module.exports (C:\wamp64\www\newGitRepo\storage\framework\ssr\f8ef279e430bf74f0394a21851fce98 ▶
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\newGitRepo\storage\framework\ssr\f8ef279e430bf74f0394a21851fce988.js:201:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
 (View: C:\wamp64\www\newGitRepo\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)
```

i have tried putting windows ={} empty object

Comment: window is a browser object, when you work on the backend there's no such thing.

Comment: "i have tried putting windows ={} empty object"
i specified this becauseithought people would suggest that 
i know that but reactjs uses windows object right

Comment: Anyone can use it if u re in the browser, u can't use it without previously defining it elsewhere

Comment: @Koop4 i know that but reactjs internal thing i cant control right it is calling this window object.

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial you're following?

Comment: React is not using windows object. React has different renderers for different environments. One of the reasons that they can have different renderers like server render, browser renderer or react native renderer is that core doesn't depend on such environemtn specific objects. In your error, it's clear that your webpack is producing code dependent on windows.

Comment: I'd suggest to create a separate frontend application though. It would be much easier to maintain and find documentations with a different server

Comment: @apokryfos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFMXkgLPewg

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı thank you for your suggestion i m looking for something which will save little time whatever you suggest will take lot of time to build the web app again for server side i just came accross next.js does anyone has any idea about its implementation with react for ssr

Comment: This is just too broad, there's a lot of places where things could have gone wrong. Instead of this error stack (which is not useful) can you share how you are including the ssr in your view as well as your server root file?

Comment: I have fixed this issue but there many other complications with SSR i have to modify each and every plugin for SSR. What is best way to use React with SSR and laravel 
1.@DoğancanArabacı gave good suggestion of changing and keeping frontend code separate but in that case i will have to keep two version of my code right one in laravel other in React 
2.Other option i was thinking of was shifting to NEXT.js

Comment: @AkshayShetty How did you fix this exact issue? `tvar jsonpArray = window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || [];`

Comment: @senty just remove all occurences of window and replace this something everyone uses 
`export const history =  (url = '/') => {
  // Create a history depending on the environment
    return (
      !window
        ? createMemoryHistory({
            initialEntries: [url]
         })
       : createBrowserHistory()
    )
  } `